# Execute CRON 2 and 3 times per month?

Tags: php, cron, execute

I have following issue.
I need to run same script (with different args) in different 5 different dates.

- 1x per month
- 2x per month
- 3x per month
- 4x per month
- every day

My current code:

1x month (run every month 1st day, 9:00)

```
0 9 1 * * php /script.php 1
```

**2x month (need to setup cron)**

```
? php /script.php 2
```

**3x month (need to setup cron)**

```
? php /script.php 3
```

4x month (run every Monday, 9:00)

```
0 9 * * 1 php /script.php 4
```

every day (run every day, 9:00)

```
0 9 * * * php /script.php e
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crontab help gives you the order of time values

> To define the time you can provide concrete values for minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon), and day of week (dow) or use '*'

You did not specify any fixed day, so I'll put sample data for you.

This cron will run every 1st and 15th at midnight

```
0 0 1,15 * * /script.php 2
```

This other every 1st,10th and 20th at midnight

```
0 0 1,10,20 * * /script.php 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This should run at 4pm on day x,y, and z of month 06 (June):

```
0 0 16 [x],[y],[z] [06] * /whatever.script
```

Every day is easy:

```
@daily /whatever.script
```